# how to seperate list of words with '->' in python 3

Tags: python

How do you seperate list of words with '->' or any other char?
I tried the `.join()` method but it doesn't make any change.
It seperated the letters just like split with comma.

```
new_list = ['a' ,'b' ,'c','d']
'->'.join(new_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Please add input, expected output and the code that you have tried.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You want a list of elements but instead of a comma you want an arrow?

Comment: yes, i thought that join could help me

Comment: @may .join doesn't modify the existing list. It creates a new string. In your code above, you just need to assign the output of `'->'.join(new_list)` to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean with "list of words".

If, for example, you have a string `l = "this, is, a, list, of, words"`, you can do:

```
result = l.replace(', ','->')
```

which results in `this->is->a->list->of->words`.

If you need something like: `l = ["aba","bac","co"]` to `"a->b->c"`, then:

```
result = '->'.join(l)
```

that gives `aba->bac->co`.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information information join is the opposite of split. Note that both operation returns a result and do not modify the variable in place. So you will need either to affect the result in a variable or use it directly.

```
>>> '->'.join(['foo', 'bar', '42'])
'foo->bar->42'
```

Please provide the value of new_list and how you test it does not work ?

Comment: If it doesn't modify the variable I guess I must use print, I think that was the problem